# New WebMethod in Netbeans can't be called by PHP client

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, webmethod

I try to solve this all day, I do not understand.
I'm trying to create a new web module in a web service. I use NetBeans and GlassFish. When I test the webmethod with a test service, it works. But when I try to call it from a php client, I can not.
There is already another web module that works well, and I can call them from the client. As soon as I changed the name, I can't call them anymore.
I have no idea.
Thanks for answering.

php consumer

```
<?php
session_start();

function affiche()
    {
    $UEopt = new SoapClient("localhost:8080/UEOptionnelles/UEoptWebService?wsdl");
    $result = $UEopt->listSemestre(array(
        "Nom" => ""
    )); // On affiche le resultat de l'appel du web service
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result->return) / 5; $i++)
        {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "\n <u>Nom</u> : ";
        print_r($result->return[1 + ($i * 5) ]);
        echo " - <u>Parcours</u> : ";
        print_r($result->return[2 + ($i * 5) ]);
        echo " - <u>Année</u> : ";
        print_r($result->return[3 + ($i * 5) ]);
        echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
</web-app>
```

java service definition

```
 /**
 * Méthode listUE
 */
 @WebMethod(operationName = "listUEParEtu")
public List listUEParEtu(@WebParam(name = "Nom") Integer NumEtu) {
    // chargement du driver SqLite
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        System.out.println(" driver SqLite ok");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Impossible de charger le driver SqLite.");
    }
    try 
    {
    // chargement de la base     
        String chemin=this.getClass().getResource("/NetBeans.db").getPath();
        System.out.println(chemin);
        Connection connection2=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+chemin);
        //String requete = "SELECT * FROM UE "
        //        +"WHERE NomUE like '%"+NumEtu+"%';";
        String requete = "SELECT * FROM Choix "
                + "WHERE  Choix.idUtilisateur='"+ NumEtu +"' ;";

        Statement statement2= connection2.createStatement();
        ResultSet executeQuery=statement2.executeQuery(requete);
```

Comment: Sorry for my awfull english, i'm french

Comment: Can you post a configuration files and how are you make the service expose?

Comment: Hello, tks for answering. Here are the config files in netbeans :
( source in web.xml )

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>

Comment: I'm not sure what's the service expose

Comment: however, this is how i call the service in php :

<?php
session_start();

function affiche()
{
$UEopt = new SoapClient ("http://localhost:8080/UEOptionnelles/UEoptWebService?wsdl");
$result = $UEopt->listSemestre(array("Nom"=>""));
// On affiche le resultat de l'appel du web service

for ($i = 0; $i <  count($result->return)/5; $i++) {
  echo "<pre>";
  echo "\n <u>Nom</u> : " ;print_r($result->return[1+($i*5)]);
  echo " - <u>Parcours</u> : " ;print_r($result->return[2+($i*5)]);
  echo " - <u>Année</u> : " ;print_r($result->return[3+($i*5)]);
  echo "</pre>";
}
}

Comment: sorry i'm very new, i don't know how to post code properly

Comment: No problem, I'm talking about add in your post not in the comments.. And please the java service definition too.

Comment: Hello again, Sorry i was away for the week-end . Below is the start of a webmethod of my code as you asked ( I hope that's what you mean )
But here is the thing : something weird happened. Netbeans run BY ITSELF the debugger mode and.... solve the problem ! But i still don't know what it was ?!? the debugger console said : "add to localhost 9009"
Do you know what it means, and what was i doing wrong ?
Again thanks a lot for your help, that's very kind of you.